# Secure a class for a form hydratation : is this a good way?

Tags: php, forms, class, post

I use PHP classes for managing users accounts and I wonder if what I'm doing is correct.
I directly use the `$_POST['form']` for hydrate User objects.
But there is some field that I don't want user to modify (i.e. : `Id_user`, `admin_level`,...) so i use an argument in each setID or `setAdmin_level (a boolean called $force)` :

```
public function __construct(array $donnees = null, $forcer = false)
{
  if($donnees){
    $this->hydrate($donnees,$forcer);
  }
}
public function hydrate(array $donnees, $forcer = false)
{
    foreach($donnees as $champ => $valeur){
      $method = 'set'.ucfirst($champ);
      if(method_exists($this,$method))
      {
        if($forcer){
          try {
            $this->$method($this->securite($valeur), true);
          }catch(Exception $e){
            $this->$method($this->securite($valeur));
          }
        }else {
            $this->$method($this->securite($valeur));
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a "secured" setter :

```
    public function setId_user($id_user, $forcer = false)
{
  if(is_numeric($id_user)&&$forcer)
  {
      $this->_id_user = $id_user;
      return true;
  }else {
    $this->addErreur('id_user','User ID incorrect');
    return false;
  }

}
```

So, in order to register a new user, I hydrate a new User object with the form POST :

```
$user = new User($_POST[form], false);
```

And I need to set the $force bool to true for creating a new User from an Id or if I want to set a field protected.

```
$userManager->getUserFromId(new User(['id_user' => 1], true));
```

Or

```
$userManager->getUserFromEmail(new User(['email' => "my_email@email.com"], true));
```

Is this a good way?

Comment: This question should probably be posted on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes, I didn't know this website.
Thanks !

Comment: This all looks very weird to me. Constructors outside a class, variable method calling, two different languages, several pieces of code. I guess that it all make perfect sense to you, but I can't figure out how it all hangs together. Please don't post it like this on Code Review, read the [guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) there first.

Comment: I haven't pull all my User class because there is a lot of setter/getters that aren't interesting.
Do i need to put more details ?

Comment: Ah, so the first bit of code is from the User class, perhaps? What about the second bit?

Comment: Anyway, I get it, but it is very hard to judge, if what you're doing is correct, with such a sparse selection of code snippets. So, for Code Review you have to post more than this. There your code is really reviewed, from several angles: Style, performance, security, etc.